# docker exec -> permission denied when executing through ssh

Tags: docker, ssh

I am trying to execute a command on a docker container that is running in a remote server. I am running most commands through ssh and they all work correctly. However, this command modifies the file `/etc/environment` and I get a "permission denied" error.

The command in question is `docker exec container_id echo 'WDS_SOCKET_PORT=XXXXX' >> /etc/environment`

- If I run the command from the docker host, it works
- If I run a simple command remotely using `ssh user@ip docker exec container_id ls`, it works
- If I run this command remotely using `ssh user@ip docker exec container_id echo 'WDS_SOCKET_PORT=XXXXX' >> /etc/environment` I get `sh: 1: cannot create /etc/environment: Permission denied`

I tried adding the option `-u 0` to the docker exec command with no luck.

I don't mind making changes to the Dockerfile since I can kill, remove or recreate this container with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error isn't coming from docker or ssh, it's coming from your shell that parses the command you want to run. You are trying to modify the file on your host. To do io redirection inside the container, you need to run a shell there and parse the command with that shell.

```sh
ssh user@ip "docker exec  container_id /bin/sh -c 'echo \"WDS_SOCKET_PORT=XXXXX\" >> /etc/environment'"
```

EDIT: Note that the whole docker command should be surrounded by quotes. I believe this is because ssh might otherwise parse different parts of the command as parameters of the docker command. This way, each sub-command is clearly delimited.

Comment: I don't think the quote escape is done properly in your answer since the terminal is left waiting for more input. However, it is true it has something to do with io redirection. I tried adding double quotes `"echo 'WDS_SOCKET_PORT=49164' >> /etc/environment"` and got the same error. I managed to make it work using sed, since it does not need io redirection: `ssh user@ip docker exec container_id "sed -i '$ a\WDS_SOCKET_PORT=XXXXX' /etc/environment"`

Comment: Using sed it a good solution for me but I'll leave this open in case someone finds a way to make io redirection work, in case someone finds this question and needs that

Comment: UPDATE: sed is not really a good solution since it doesn't work unless the file already exists

Comment: Sorry, I was writing that answer from memory, quoting fixed.

Comment: I was trying to edit while you edited, this new answer still doesn't work but I found the solution: `ssh user@ip "docker exec  container_id sh -c 'echo \"WDS_SOCKET_PORT=XXXXX\" > /etc/environment'"` I need quotes surrounding the docker command so the ssh command is parsed correctly. Otherwise, I think it detects the echo part as parameters to the docker command. I'll edit the answer as soon as SO lets me

Comment: When you add `ssh`, there's likely another shell getting added to the parsing, first the shell on your host, then the shell on the host you ssh'd to, and then the shell inside the container. You need to be sure only the last shell sees the `>>`.

Comment: exactly! hence the quotes surrounding the docker command. I edited the answer but it is pending approval

Comment: could you approve the changes so I can mark the answer as the solution? @BMitch